# Unable to connect with MongoDb using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating `MERN` stack app I am trying to connect my app with `MongoDb` database.I am using `Mongoose` library to connect with `MongoDb.I am getting error below:

**Error**

> TypeError: callback is not a function
>   ['server]     at $initialConnection.$initialConnection.then (H:\React projects\MyBlog\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:744:13)
>   ['server]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Here is my code below:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(require('./routes/saveData.js'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port,() => {

   console.log(`Server is running on ${port}.`);
});
```

**saveData.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const blogs = require('../models/blogPost');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

const dburl = 'mongodb+srv://example:example@cluster1-5wp.mongodb.net/ExpDb?retryWrites=true'

router.post('/save',(req,res) => {

   const data = {

       title: req.body.title,
       detail: req.body.detail
     }

     const newBlog = new blogs(data);

    mongoose.connect(dburl, {useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology:true}).then((resp) =>{

          resp.send("Connected");          
          console.log("connected");
        }).catch((err) => { 
            console.log("database error: ",err);
        });

  });

module.exports = router;
```

Below is mongoose schema:
**blogPost.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BlogPostSchema = new Schema({

  title:String,
  body:String,
  date:{
      type:String,
      dafault:Date.now()
    }
});

const BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost',BlogPostSchema);

module.exports = BlogPost;
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose returned promise value is `resp`. Server response object which is having `.send` method is `res`. Try below :

```
router.post('/save', (req, res) => {
...
    mongoose.connect(dburl, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology:true}).then((resp) =>{         
        // res not resp
        res.send("Connected");          
        console.log("connected");
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation Reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#callback)

Syntax from the documentation,

```
mongoose.connect(uri, options).then(
  () => { /** ready to use. The `mongoose.connect()` promise resolves to mongoose instance. */ },
  err => { /** handle initial connection error */ }
);
```

Code

```
router.post('/save',(req,res) => {

    mongoose.connect(dburl, {useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology:true})
      .then(() =>{        
              res.send("Connected");          
              console.log("connected");
            },
           (err)=> console.log("database error: ",err);)        
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mongoose connect doesn't have a callback

```
mongoose.connect(dburl, {useNewUrlParser: true},{useUnifiedTopology:true});
```

this should work. And then to update you should use the mongoose save method on the model object.

```
BlogPost.save();
```